# Why UIActionSheet not support my landscape?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a app with tabbarcontroller, two controller with it, and now in one controller I show a uiactionsheet in portrait model:

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                   initWithTitle:@""
                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Del"
                   otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];

```
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
actionSheet.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[actionSheet release];
```

and I found that when I change the mode to landscape, it not work, because it not response the controller delegate:

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

and if the actionsheet not show , the controller can change for landscape , why? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: ok, I got a [answer][1], it will solove my problem!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859352/iphone-uiactionsheet-auto-rotating-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some text..."
                           delegate:self
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete"
                  otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2",nil];

  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0 ||
      UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
  } else {
    [sheet showInView:self.view.window];
  }
```

Comment: sorry, it not work. and I found that when I used [sheet showInView:self.view], and show a UIActionSheet with portrait mode, and then turn to landscape mode, it not response the delegate:

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

why???

Comment: ok, I got a answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859352/iphone-uiactionsheet-auto-rotating-not-working